# Magento 2: Want to change the location of Product Page "Your added .....shopping cart" message, under the addto cart button

Tags: magento2, cart, product-page, magento2.3.4, success-message

I have tried to relocate in layouts XML file, but it's not working.
the file is in the/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/messages/**addCartSuccessMessage.phtml**
I just want to put this line under the add to cart button or after the short description pannal.
(Magento 2.3.4)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the bellow steps to move the success message to the desired place.

1. Create the `default.xml` in your module (app/code/VendorName/ModuleName).

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <container name="page.messages" 
                       htmlTag="div" 
                       htmlClass="page messages" 
                       after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                       name="ajax.message.placeholder"
                       template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" 
                       name="messages" as="messages"
                       template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Below is the result for the theme Magento Luma:
   [image: Success Message Moved]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works
can you please tell me how to post it above the description

Comment: ok it's solved I put before instead of after, Thanks Man

Comment: Sure man. I was working on that only. Happy that you were able to get the result. Are you going to accept the answer?

Comment: yes, i gave the thumbs up